# Facebook Login is returning 'Undefined' Fields in user profile and it doesn't return email. MEANJs + Passport-facebook

Tags: facebook, authentication, meanjs, passport-facebook

I am using Meanjs.org boilerplate and Facebook Signup returns me to the Signup page.
Following are the steps that I have taken so far.

**1)** Setting up the Facebook App **Site URL**

> http://localhost:3000/

and the callback **URI of OAuth**

> http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback

**2)** Placing the APP_ID and APP_Secret in as Client_ID and Client_Secret

```
    facebook: {
    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_ID || '*****',
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET || '*****',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback',
    profileFields: ['id','emails', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'displayName', 'link', 'about_me', 'photos' ]
},
```

**3) Code is as follows**

--Routes

```
// Setting the facebook oauth routes
app.route('/auth/facebook').get(passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    scope: ['email']
}));
app.route('/auth/facebook/callback').get(users.oauthCallback('facebook'));
```

-- The oauthCallback function,

```
    exports.oauthCallback = function(strategy) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate(strategy, function(err, user, redirectURL) {
            if (err || !user) {
                console.log('1' + err);
                //console.log(user);
                return res.redirect('/#!/signin');
            }
            req.login(user, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('2' + err);
                    return res.redirect('/#!/signin');
                }

                return res.redirect(redirectURL || '/');
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    };
};
```

-- Passport-Facebook Strategy

```
module.exports = function() {
// Use facebook strategy
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: config.facebook.clientID,
        clientSecret: config.facebook.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL,
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

        console.log('facebook Strategy Started');
        // Set the provider data and include tokens
        var providerData = profile._json;
        providerData.accessToken = accessToken;
        providerData.refreshToken = refreshToken;

    //  console.log(JSON.stringify(profile));
        console.log(profile);

    //  console.log(JSON.stringify(profile.name.givenName));

        // Create the user OAuth profile
        var providerUserProfile = {
            firstName: profile.name.givenName,
            lastName: profile.name.familyName,
            displayName: profile.displayName,
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
            username: profile.username,
            provider: 'facebook',
            providerIdentifierField: 'id',
            providerData: providerData
        };

        //console.log('provider' + providerUserProfile);
        // Save the user OAuth profile
        users.saveOAuthUserProfile(req, providerUserProfile, done);
    }
));
```

};

**4) Debugging**

Logging err under oauthCallback function returns the following,

> 1TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

What Facebook returns as profile in Passport-Facebook module is as follows,

> { id: 'Id_of_the_person',
>     username: **undefined**,
>     displayName: 'Full_name_of_person',
>     name:
>      { familyName: **undefined**,
>        givenName: **undefined**,
>        middleName: **undefined** },
>     gender: **undefined**,
>     profileUrl: **undefined**,
>     provider: 'facebook',
>     _raw: '{"name":"Full_name_of_person","id":"Id_of_the_person"}',
>     _json:
>      { name: 'Id_of_the_person',
>        id: 'Id_of_the_person',
>        accessToken: 'access_token_value',
>        refreshToken: **undefined** } }

Can anyone be kind to guide me about getting the correct user profile from Facebook including user email?

Thank you so much.

Comment: API v2.4 changes regarding fields, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes // The actual API request made needs to be modified accordingly; if your framework/SDK does not expose that request to you, then you need to ask them to adapt their code.

Comment: Check the version of passport-facebook in the boilerplate. I had a similar situation and upgrading to version 2.0.0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have my profile fields set to the following

```
profileFields: ['email','id', 'first_name', 'gender', 'last_name', 'picture']
```

Even though you set email it might return emails if the user has multiple emails. So you need to check if email was returned profile.email or profile.emails[0].value. You must also check if it is undefined, because there is people that register with facebook that never verify their email account and there is people that sign up with a phone number, in both those cases their emails will always be undefined.

you want to check that any required fields have values.

```
var email = profile.email || profile.emails[0].value;
            if (! email){
              console.log('this user has no email in his FB');
              var err = {message:'this user is missing an email'};
              return done(err);
            }
```

now i can do this if they have an email

```
newUser.facebook.email = email;
```

if they don't have an email you can set a session for profile and send them to a page that asks them to enter an email.

It sounds like a pain, but you can never trust information from a third party api to have values.

Most of the passport examples I've seen online are wrong. They all assume an email is present.

Answer (score 0):

First, *profileFields* field does not obey to [Portable Contacts convention](http://portablecontacts.net/draft-spec.html) - and you can find the convention for passportjs [here](http://passportjs.org/docs/profile).

Second, in your example, after removing removed 'about_me', the Facebook signup returns no error. Before removing 'about_me', I had a different error: *Tried accessing nonexisting field (about_me) on node type (User)*

If the error persist, see [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) serie of 5 tutorials which helps me when I was doing the sign up page to authenticate with social networks accounts.